# Automatically bold math symbols when \bfseries or \textbf is used

Tags: math-mode, symbols, amsmath, bold, inline

There are a lot of questions asking how to get math symbols to appear in bold, which I know that you can do with `\mathbf` and `amsmath`'s `\boldsymbol`.

**But is there a way to *automatically* bold my inline mathematical equations when (and only when) the surrounding text-mode contents are bold?**

For instance, I would like the following:

```latex
The quick brown fox \textbf{jumps over \( \sin (256) \) lazy dogs.} \\
The quick brown fox \textbf{jumps over $\sin (256)$ lazy dogs.} \\
The quick brown fox jumps over \( \sin (256) \) lazy dogs. \\
The quick brown fox jumps over $\sin (256)$ lazy dogs. \\
The quick brown fox {\bfseries jumps over \( \sin (256) \) lazy dogs.} \\
The quick brown fox {\bfseries jumps over $\sin (256)$ lazy dogs.} \\
The quick brown fox \textbf{jumps over \( 3^{2\cos 10} \) lazy dogs.} \\
The quick brown fox \textbf{jumps over $3^{2\cos 10}$ lazy dogs.} \\
The quick brown fox {\bfseries jumps over \( 3^{2\cos 10} \) lazy dogs.} \\
The quick brown fox {\bfseries jumps over $3^{2\cos 10}$ lazy dogs.}
```

to render as:

> The quick brown fox **jumps over sin(256) lazy dogs.**
> The quick brown fox **jumps over sin(256) lazy dogs.**
> The quick brown fox jumps over sin(256) lazy dogs.
> The quick brown fox jumps over sin(256) lazy dogs.
> The quick brown fox **jumps over sin(256) lazy dogs.**
> The quick brown fox **jumps over sin(256) lazy dogs.**
> The quick brown fox **jumps over 3<sup>2 cos(10)</sup> lazy dogs.**
> The quick brown fox **jumps over 3<sup>2 cos(10)</sup> lazy dogs.**
> The quick brown fox **jumps over 3<sup>2 cos(10)</sup> lazy dogs.**
> The quick brown fox **jumps over 3<sup>2 cos(10)</sup> lazy dogs.**

Comment: There is a reason that this isn't done automatically.  In math above a certain level, it's not unusual to define the "same" letter in different styles (italic, boldface, script, ...) to mean different things.  Automatically setting all math letters as bold in, say, a bold section heading could change the meaning and cause serious confusion and lead to misunderstanding or lack of comprehension by the reader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
\newcommand\allbold[1]{\textbf{\boldmath#1}}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\allbold[1]{\textbf{\boldmath#1}}
\begin{document}

The quick brown fox {jumps over \( \sin (256) \) lazy dogs.} 

The quick brown fox \allbold{jumps over \( \sin (256) \) lazy dogs.} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can I somehow redefine `\textbf` itself to have this functionality? One of my goals is for mathematical terms in my `glossaries-extra` glossary to appear in bold.

Comment: you could, but I wouldn't: simply use `\bfseries\boldmath` when specifying your glossaries setup

Comment: Great idea—thank you!