Automated text style in math mode
I'd like to define an environment where I can write text and formulas between dollars. I want these formulas, only in that environment, to have a specific style like mathrm for instance.
It would help me in two situations :

To define an environment where text is bold (which is quite simple), and where I don't have to use \boldsymbol so that formulas are bold two; it would be automatic. For now, I do that (without an automated environment) : \textbf{j'écris une formule avec $\boldsymbol{f}$ qui est importante}.
I've got this command for writing an erroneous math text with a different font :


\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathpzc}{OT1}{pzc}{m}{it} 
\newenvironment{erreur}{\fontfamily{pzc}\selectfont *(}{)}


but, same thing, I have to write \begin{erreur} La dérivée de $\mathpzc{x \mapsto sin(x)}$ est $\mathpzc{x \mapsto - cos(x)}$. \end{erreur} so that math mode has a specific style.
I would like to do something like "set a math font" locally. Ideas?
This is what I have now and don't want to change (only the way to get it ;) )!

(I was asked to put a code. Here it is :
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathpzc}{OT1}{pzc}{m}{it} 
\newenvironment{erreur}{\fontfamily{pzc}\selectfont *(}{)}

\begin{document}

\begin{erreur} La dérivée de $\mathpzc{x \mapsto sin(x)}$ est $\mathpzc{x \mapsto - cos(x)}$. \end{erreur}

\begin{erreur} La dérivée de $x \mapsto sin(x)$ est $x \mapsto - cos(x)$. \end{erreur}

\end{document}

I'd like to change my environment erreur so that the second line code would provide automatically the result from the first.)

Welcome to TeX.SX! Please don't post code fragments. Instead, put your fragments into a complete compilable document that shows the problem ( with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}.).

This doesn't make sense. I'm trying to define an environment from scratch (in an article, and there's no packages pre-required). I think writing a MWE would just darken my question.

The reason for the request for compilable code is that potential helpers want to be able to test their answers before posting them, and if they guess wrong, everyone's time is wasted.  You know what you are using, but we don't.

OK, I've added something to my question.

Maybe if you can use XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX then use \setmathfont + mathversion. How to change the MATH and Text fonts for just a part of the document? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange ■ see also fonts - Using \DeclareMathVersion - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange

Partial duplicate (for the bold part): https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/667363/automatically-bold-math-symbols-when-bfseries-or-textbf-is-used

Or a newer one that actually hooks into \textbf (but that advices against it) is https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/347146/using-textbf-to-make-also-math-bold-in-sentence

For the question about the pzc font you can hook into $ using \everymath. This is not always very robust but maybe it is sufficient for your purposes. This approach requires one additional step, which is to change \mathpzc from a command that takes an argument into a switch that changes the font permanently until the next switch or until the end of the group (similar to \textbf{} vs. \bfseries for text for example), which can be done with \@fontswitch.
This command takes two arguments: the first argument is used in text mode and the second one is used in math mode. If called within \everymath the first argument is never used but you can put something sensible there just for consistency.
If the \everymath hook is placed inside of \newenvironment{erreur} then math outside of the environment is not affected.
MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathpzc}{OT1}{pzc}{m}{it} 
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{erreur}{%
\everymath{\@fontswitch{\normalfont\rmfamily}{\mathpzc}}%
\fontfamily{pzc}\selectfont *(}%
{)}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
La dérivée de $x \mapsto sin(x)$ est $x \mapsto cos(x)$.

\begin{erreur} La dérivée de $\mathpzc{x \mapsto sin(x)}$ est $\mathpzc{x \mapsto - cos(x)}$. \end{erreur}

La dérivée de $x \mapsto sin(x)$ est $x \mapsto cos(x)$.

\begin{erreur} La dérivée de $x \mapsto sin(x)$ est $x \mapsto - cos(x)$. \end{erreur}

La dérivée de $x \mapsto sin(x)$ est $x \mapsto cos(x)$.
\end{document}

Result:

